# How do I create a formula that divides certain cells by other cells only if the former cell equals a certain value?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to create a productivity analysis and I am trying to divide the amount of employees on shift at a particular time and day by the revenue at the same time. I want the formula to be able to recognize that if there is 1 person on shift, it should divide by the revenue at that particular time. I am ultimately trying to average the revenue earned at certain times by only having 1 employee on shift vs 2,3,4...

The formula I initially started with was `=IF('Employee Data'!B2:B85="1", (1/'Revenue Data'!B2:B85))`. I had hoped it would result in giving me the productivity values each time we had 1 employee on shift, which I could then average out. However, this only responds with a "False" value.

[Formula sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvonm.png)
[Revenue sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD2CQ.png)
[Employee Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmuXE.png)

Comment: What's the point of taking "employees / revenue"?  I can understand doing it the other way around, to get dollars per employee, and it that case you don't have to special case 1 at all.  BTW, your `=IF` has a string `"1"` instead of an integer.